# Why is List[Int, Int] not a valid Scala type?

Tags: scala

This works fine:

```
def list: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3)
```

But this does not:

```
def list: List[Int, Int] = List((1, 1), (1, 2))
```

> Error : :28: error: wrong number of type arguments for List, should be 1

What is the problem?

Comment: The things in square brackets are the type arguments. `[Int, Int]` <- That's two type arguments.

Comment: If you type `:t List((1, 1), (1, 2))` into the REPL, it will tell you what the type is (`List[(Int, Int)]`).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Signature should be:

```
def list: List[(Int,Int)]
```

Which means: a *tuple* of two `Int`s

Answer (score 4):

The original question is

> Why is List[Int, Int] not a valid Scala type?

And the answer is that `List` constructor is parameterized with a single type parameter, so in your case in order to make it work you need to transform 2 parameters into a single one by adding parenthesis around them to make a `Tuple`:

```
def list: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1, 1), (1, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

The argument/ type you define after `List` within the `[` `]` - brackets defines what type of data the list should contain.

The first definition `List[Int]` says you expect a List of Integers if you want to have a list of `Int` pairs you can use

```
List[(Int,Int)]
```

or

```
List[Tuple2[Int,Int]]
```

Comment: `List[Tuple2[Int]]` is as invalid as `List[Int, Int]`…